# Input in Korean is ignored in WYSIWYG html editor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wysiwyg, redactor

Environment:

Rails 4.0.0
Ruby 1.9.3

I'm having a very odd behavior with my application right now. For a simple text input field, whenever I write in Korean the content is not submitted. I'm trying to debug this problem but not getting anything solved.

To take input, I use Redactor. Whenever I don't use it, Korean is once again working.

**from view**

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('.my_post_body').redactor({ 
      minHeight: 300
   });
  });
</script>

<%= simple_form_for @post do |f| %>
 <%= f.input :body, input_html: { class: "my_post_body" } %>
 <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

**from DB**

```
 id |         created_at         |         updated_at         |          body          |  title   

 44 | 2013-07-03 03:41:12.829545 | 2013-07-03 03:41:12.829545 |                        | worksㅎ
```

Could this be a problem with Rails 4.0.0?

Comment: Please check your log to see what parameters were actually posted to the server.

Comment: The param for body is empty ONLY when I input in Korean. When the content is English, the param is not empty and it's stored into body without any problem.